# Merge different Arrays and Calculate Average price Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, math

I am trying to calculate and create an Array with Average Prices for different stocks.

For every stock, I have the Data in this format:

```
{
  prices: [
    [
      1634304009628,
      0.7118076876774715
    ],
    [
      1634307586874,
      0.7063647246346818
    ],
    [
      1634311139365,
      0.7049706990925925
    ],
    [
      1634313858611,
      0.7085543691926037
    ],
    [
      1634318343009,
      0.7057442983161784
    ]
  ]
}
```

For every stock API call I get the data like how I posted above, it has 2 values timestamp and the second one is the price. Now let's say I want the average trend for 5 stocks I will get the data in 5 different arrays and I just want to somehow make an average out of those 5 arrays in one to find the trend.

For the final result, I want the Array to be in the same format just with the calculated average altogether (the goal is to identify the trend direction).

What would be the best way to do that? I am Using React

Comment: Can you clarify what result you expected? Write the `prices` object as it should be.

Comment: Well for every stock API call I get the data like how I posted above, it has 2 values timestamp and the second one is the price. Now let's say I want the average trend for 5 stocks I will get the data and I just want to somehow make an average out of those 5 arrays in one.

Answer (score 0):

first create and array of prices only and then using reduce you can just do this:

```js
let myObj = {
  prices: [
    [
      1634304009628,
      0.7118076876774715
    ],
    [
      1634307586874,
      0.7063647246346818
    ],
    [
      1634311139365,
        0.7049706990925925
    ],
    [
      1634313858611,
      0.7085543691926037
    ],
    [
      1634318343009,
      0.7057442983161784
    ]
  ]
};
const average = arr => arr.reduce( ( p, c ) => p + c, 0 ) / arr.length;
const pricesArr = myObj.prices.map(function(value,index) { return value[1]; })
const result = average( pricesArr );
console.log(result);
```